# Is there a way to push out printer configs without a domain environment?

Tags: ip, printing

All the printers on our network are IP printers, is there a way to push out the printers to users without a domain environment?

Comment: Just to clarify, but I'm assuming from the title that you are a Windows shop?

Answer (score 2):

Psexec would work well with a batch file.  Personally, I just leave a folder with all of the printers install scripts (one for just adding, and one to install and make it the default printer) on a network share (we don't happen to have the printers listed in the directory quite yet), but since you don't have a domain, it's easier to just psexec these from your local machine.  [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314486) will give you some more information on how to do so in depth, but the basic syntax to install an IP printer via command line is as follows:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Test Printer" /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /r "IP_157.57.50.98" /m "HP Laserjet 4000 Series PCL" /Z
```

Obviously, change things like the printer name and IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Misread the question. This works for domain enviroments only:
Depends on the OS Version (both client and server). If you're running a 2008 Server environment you have access to Group Policy Preferences, which include lots of printer settings. The GP Preferences client is built-in for WIndows Vista and 7, but you can download the client for XP/Win2003 also. It's up there on Microsofts download side (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=group+policy+preference&displaylang=en&stype=s_basic)

Comment: Aren't Group Polices in a Domain Environment?

Comment: absolutely. But as I state above, the level of printer control varies greatly with the OS versions.

Comment: my bad, read the question wrong :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've used [wpkg](http://www.wpkg.org/) for managing system settings as well as installed software when a domain is not required or available.